# Call JavaScript function in jinja for loop

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have an HTML page, In the variable `schedule` has sequential decimal number in seconds.

My purpose is create a function to convert all these numbers in time using JavaScript/jQuery, 
    but i could not understand, how can I invoke my function to convert all items?

```
<html>
    <body>
        // Jinja code

        {% for item in schedule %}

        {{ convertDecimal_to_time(item.someDecimal) }}

        {% endfor %}

    </body>
</html>

<script>
    covertdecimal_to_time(input_number){
        .....
        return time;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jinja code runs on your server. The Javascript runs on the client's browser.

You can't call a javascript function in a Jinja for-loop, because those two things happen at completely different times, on different machines.

The best approach for this scenario is to write a Python function, not a Javascript function, and run it as a [filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters). You can add a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters) to the template engine.

Comment: those links are not working..